# tar command execution from java does not work as expected

Tags: java, bash, tar

tar command execution from java does not work as expected. Below are the lines of code for the same. The tar file is getting created, but it is empty, though there are matching files in the directory to tar. Not sure what could be the issue. Any inputs will be helpful.

Note: The same command when I execute it on terminal works fine, with tar ball having all the intended files.

```
String cmd = "tar -cvzf /tmp/logs.tar.gz /home/test/log/status.*"
try {
    Process p1 = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(cmd);
    p1.waitFor();
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: how do you run java class? user used to run java class same as when command run via terminal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Obviously the expansion `status.*` does not work. Try without it. As an alternative resolve the input files/directories within Java code. Use `java.nio` to do this.

As Gyro Gearless mentions in the comments it is also possible to wrap the tar command in a script and execute this from Java code.

Comment: Thanks NaN. I thik you are right, but there re thousands of files and I have to tar few hundreds out of them. Resolving all of them in code is not feasible...what say?

Comment: Put your your tar command in a little shell script and use /bin/bash to run it. Should do the trick.